# get phone's name from CBPheripheral IOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

I am developing an app IOS app the uses the CoreBluetooth framework, I am trying to get the phone's name from the CBPeripheral object on "didDiscoverPheripheral" method and add it to an array so I can display it on a tableView. I mean the "phone's name" to be something like "Dan's iPhone".
later on I would like to press the row on the tableView so I can connect to that device.

I have tried :

```
 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral    *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);

if (_discoveredPeripheral != peripheral) {
    // Save a local copy of the peripheral, so CoreBluetooth doesn't get rid of it
    _discoveredPeripheral = peripheral;

    // And connect
    NSLog(@"Connecting to peripheral %@", peripheral);
   // here i want to add the name of the device to an array
}
}
```

any ideas??

Comment: NSLog(@"device name: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] name]);

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add Peripherals after you discover and than create another method inside your Bluetooth class and call that to connect to the selected device from TableView:

```
 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral    *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

     NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@", peripheral.name, RSSI);
      // add found devices to class variable NSMutableArray<CBPeripheral> *foundPeripherals
     // do not forget to initialize it
     [self.foundPeripherals addObject:peripheral];

}

// create a connect method where you pass the device selected identifier
- (void) connect:(NSString*)uuidString {
    CBPeripheral* peripheral;
    for (peripheral in self.foundPeripherals){
        if(peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateDisconnected){
            // this will invoke didConnectPeripheral once connection 
            // set successfully
            [self connectPeripheral:peripheral];
        }
    }
}

// store the connected peripheral
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:     (CBPeripheral *)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"Attempted connection to peripheral %@ succeed.", [peripheral name]);
    // store the connected device info in class property
    self.peripheral = peripheral;
}
```